# Quotes in Bash pattern substitution variable expansion

Tags: bash

Should I quote variables when performing Bash parameter expansion?

For example in the following, should `"${E}"` be in quotes?

```
(
E="-END"

X=(ABC 123 "ABC 123")
X=("${X[@]/%/"${E}"}")

IFS=$'\n'
echo "${X[*]}"
)
```

I've noticed on 4.2 versions of bash this will result in the following output

```
ABC"-END"
123"-END"
ABC 123"-END"
```

But on 4.3 versions of bash this will result in the following output

```
ABC-END
123-END
ABC 123-END
```

Is this a bug that was fixed?

*Edit.* Changed `"$E"` to `"${E}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a bug, but documented in the [official change log](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/CHANGES):

> This document details the changes between this version, bash-4.3-alpha,
>   and the previous version, bash-4.2-release.
>
> ...
>
> zz. When using the pattern substitution word expansion, bash now runs the
>       replacement string through quote removal, since it allows quotes in that
>       string to act as escape characters.  This is not backwards compatible, so
>       it can be disabled by setting the bash compatibility mode to 4.2.

To toggle compatibility mode (if you want to experiment):

```
shopt -s compat42
```

and you'll see that 4.3 behaves like 4.2, and to unset it:

```
shopt -u compat42
```

Comment: awesome. going forward what would you do? use quotes?

Comment: @JamesAndrews If you don't want quotes in the output, then don't quote `$E`, and if you want quotes, then escape the quotes `\"$E\"`. This should be rather portable across versions. Another possibility is to use the `compat42` shell option to guarantee the same behavior across versions (but then you'll have to check that your Bash version is ≥4.2).